# animation visible in live preview brackets but not in ANY browser

Tags: browser, loading, preview, live, brackets

i made a loading bar for my website. On the live preview with brackets, when I scroll down to my bar, the animation become visible. When I open my html page with a browser (chrome or edge), The loading bar animation does not appear... Although I think I used the right prefixes. Below you can see my code:

```
**CSS**
.laden100 {
    animation-name: laden100;
    -webkit-animation-name: laden100;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #308355, #308355, #308355, #00cc66);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #308355, #308355, #308355, #00cc66);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

@keyframes laden100 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes laden100 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        width: 50%;
    }
}

**HTML**

  <div class="container wit mt-5">

        <h1 id="skills">Skills</h1>

        <p style="color:#308355">Below you can see my skills I have. This learning process is still ongoing. I hope to achieve at least 80% for each coding language.</p>
        <br>


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="vak">HTML</div>
                <div class="laadbalk100"></div>
                <div class="score100">%</div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>

    </div>


**JAVASCRIPT**
    <!----------------------- only load the load bar on scroll-------------->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
            $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
                // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
                if (this.hash !== "") {
                    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                    event.preventDefault();

                    // Store hash
                    var hash = this.hash;

                    // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                    // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                    }, 900, function() {

                        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                        window.location.hash = hash;
                    });
                } // End if
            });

           
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                $(".laadbalk100").each(function() {
                    var pos = $(this).offset().top;

                    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (pos < winTop + 600) {
                        $(this).addClass("laden100");
                    }
                });
            });

        })

    </script>
```

I used prefixes because I think it has something to do with browser support. According to me, Brackets uses plugins to add the right prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

OK sry Guys,

I found the answer to my own question... :D.
Because browsers have different screen resolutions, I had to increase wintop +600 to wintop +1000. See the correction below:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                $(".laadbalk100").each(function() {
                    var pos = $(this).offset().top;

                    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (pos < winTop + 1000) {
                        $(this).addClass("laden100");
                    }
                });
            });
```